# I want to let my assign html can be stable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

My canvas html will slide the whole page when I assign with any smartphone, but it won't happen on PC.

I want to know how to fix this problem and let my html can stop sliding.

I also want to ask, is it possible to let the image builded by this web auto save to google drive with using GAS?

*here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-TW">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>手寫輸入</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
    #canvas {}
    
    #canvasDiv {
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body id="bb">

    <div id="canvasDiv"></div>

    <br>

    <button id="btn_clear">清除</button>

    <button id="btn_submit">提交</button>

    <script language="javascript">
        var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var screenwidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
        var screenheight = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;

        var canvasWidth = screenwidth / 100 * 80;
        var canvasHeight = screenheight / 100 * 40;
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
        var point = {};
        point.notFirst = false;
        canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
        canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
        canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
        if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
            canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        /*var ptrn = context.createPattern(img, 'no-repeat');
        context.fillStyle = ptrn;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        */
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "Transparent.png";

        img.onload = function() {
            var ptrn = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
            context.fillStyle = ptrn;
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
            //console.log(e);
            var mouseX = e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop;
            paint = true;
            addClick(e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop);
            //console.log(e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop);
            redraw();
        });



        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
            //console.log("touch end");
            paint = false;
        });

        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
            if (paint) {
                //console.log("touchmove");
                addClick(e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
                //console.log(e.touches[0].pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.touches[0].pageY - this.offsetTop);
                redraw();
            }

        });

        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
            var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            paint = true;
            addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
            redraw();
        });
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
            if (paint) {
                addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
                redraw();
            }
        });
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
            paint = false;
        });
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
            paint = false;
        });
        document.getElementById("btn_clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
            canvas.width = canvas.width;
        });
        document.getElementById("btn_submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
            $("#qmimg").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        });


        function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
            if (event.touches.length == 1) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Faking double click for touch devices
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                if (now - timeOfLastTouch < 250) {
                    reset();
                    return;
                }
                timeOfLastTouch = now;
                mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY;
                isMouseDown = true;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {

            if (event.touches.length == 1) {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY;
            }
        }

        function onDocumentTouchEnd(event) {
            if (event.touches.length == 0) {
                event.preventDefault();
                isMouseDown = false;
            }
        }


        var clickX = new Array();
        var clickY = new Array();
        var clickDrag = new Array();
        var paint;

        function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
            clickX.push(x);
            clickY.push(y);
            clickDrag.push(dragging);
        }



        function redraw() {

            //canvas.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas
            context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            while (clickX.length > 0) {
                point.bx = point.x;
                point.by = point.y;
                point.x = clickX.pop();
                point.y = clickY.pop();
                point.drag = clickDrag.pop();
                context.beginPath();
                if (point.drag && point.notFirst) {
                    context.moveTo(point.bx, point.by);
                } else {
                    point.notFirst = true;
                    context.moveTo(point.x - 1, point.y);
                }
                context.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }

            
        }
    </script>

    <img id="qmimg" />

</body>

</html>
```